# Send GET Request in C to IPv6 web server on windows

Tags: c, sockets, web, ipv6, winsock2

I am trying to make a simple `GET` request to a webserver that has an IPv6 address, and it does not work. My code has to be available on Windows, so I use the Windows libraries, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Here is the part of the code that establishes the connection :

```
int portno = 825;
//yes, strange port number...
const char *adress = "[2a02:842a:86d1:d001:26dd:8d7a:8202:d9a3]";
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET sockfd;
char message[4096] = "GET //page//index.php?data=somedata HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: [2a02:842a:86d1:d001:26dd:8d7a:8202:d9a3]\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n\r\n");
struct hostent *server;
struct sockaddr_in6 serv_addr;
int bytes, sent, received, total;
char response[4096];
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);
sockfd = socket(AF_INET6 , SOCK_STREAM , 0 );

//while debugging i noticed that this line does not work
server = gethostbyname(adress);

memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
printf("1\n");
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);
connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
```

If anybody knows how to change this code so that it will allow IPv6 connections, please tell me :)

Comment: IPv6 address notation generally doesn't include `[` or `]`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-sessions-overview might be helpful.

Comment: @Cheatah see [RFC 2732](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2732)

Comment: @Bouloukaouze on a side note, your `GET` request is malformed. `//` needs to be just `/` instead. Only ```\``` needs to be escaped as ```\\``` in string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `gethostbyname()` cannot possibly work, as this function only works with IPv4 addresses or hostnames, while you are providing an IPv6 address in URI notation (`[addr]`). Furthermore, `gethostbyname()` is obsolete and should not be used in new code.

Since you already have an IPv6 address, you don't need to perform a lookup. You could use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://manned.org/getaddrinfo.3), but you're better off just transforming that in binary form through the much simpler [`inet_pton()`](https://manned.org/inet_pton.3). Remember that you need to remove the enclosing `[]` brackets as they are only needed for URIs, not for literal addresses.

Here's an example:

```c
const char *address = "2a02:842a:86d1:d001:26dd:8d7a:8202:d9a3";

if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, address, &serv_addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr) != 1) {
    // invalid address, handle the error somehow
}
```

Also, note that the correct `sockaddr_in6` has the following fields (see [`man 7 ipv6`](https://manned.org/ipv6.7)):

```
struct sockaddr_in6 {
    sa_family_t     sin6_family;   /* AF_INET6 */
    in_port_t       sin6_port;     /* port number */
    uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; /* IPv6 flow information */
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     /* IPv6 address */
    uint32_t        sin6_scope_id; /* Scope ID (new in 2.4) */
};

struct in6_addr {
    unsigned char   s6_addr[16];   /* IPv6 address */
};
```

While you are using `sin_addr`, `sin_family`, etc, as if it were a `sockaddr_in` structure. What you want instead is:

```
serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
serv_addr.sin6_port = htons(portno);
```

Comment: Thank you ! After a few search I was able to use it on windows and it works :) However I am still struggling with the connect line, as far as it does not seem to accept IPv6, and I can't find any ressource on how to adapt it to IPv6...

Comment: "*In case you had an hostname, you could have used `getaddrinfo()` instead*" - `getaddrinfo()` supports parsing IP address literals without performing a lookup.

Comment: @Bouloukaouze `connect()` works just fine with an IPv6 address when called on an `AF_INET6` socket. So, either your IP address is wrong, or you are using `connect()` wrong. As for a migration resource, see [IPv6 Guide for Windows Sockets Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipv6-guide-for-windows-sockets-applications-2)

Comment: Thank you, there is something I can't figure out :
My code is 
`sockfd = socket(AF_INET6 , SOCK_STREAM , 0 );
inet_pton(AF_INET6, adress, &serv_addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr);
memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
serv_addr.sin6_port = htons(portno);
if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {printf("error\n");}`
and i get the error...
sorry for the code i did not find how to put it nicely

Comment: Are you seriously doing `memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));` right after setting the IP? That can't possibly work :') you are wiping out `serv_addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr` right after setting it. Remove that `memset` call.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that makes sense, though it's a lot more complex of a function.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli not really. You give it just the IP string and the desired port, and it gives you back a populated `sockaddr_in6`. Nothing complex about that.

Comment: All right thanks, it does not work but it is still a good point :)
i tried `connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr_in6 *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))` instead of `connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))` but i get error on compilation